# does vlc support bgra color format?

Tags: libvlc

libvlc_video_set_format(player, "RGBA", size.cx, size.cy, size.cx << 2);

it can set the libvlc output RGBA pixel data, if I use opengl to render these data, it is very simple, but if I take d3d to render, I must do a RGBA to BGRA convert. I had tried "BGRA" string, but failed. Does any method to make libvlc with d3d works better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had found the answer: libvlc_video_set_format(player, "RV32", size.cx, size.cy, size.cx << 2);  this code can be set the output format to ARGB32